# Using xarray to make monthly average

Tags: python-3.x, grouping, python-xarray

I am working with `GLDAS` reanalysis data, period of `1 year`. The files are `.nc4`. I can open the files, but I can not give `groupby` for `1 month`. I do not want to do the hand or by for and I discovered that the `xarray` does `groupby`. My script is:

```
In[16]:import xarray as xr

In[17]:gldas = xr.open_mfdataset('./GLDAS_2010/*.nc4', chunks=None, concat_dim='time', preprocess=None, engine='netcdf4', lock=None,compat='minimal',coords='minimal',data_vars='minimal')

In[18]: gldas
Out[18]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                (bnds: 2, lat: 40, lon: 48, time: 365)
Coordinates:
  * lat                    (lat) float32 -34.875 -34.625 -34.375 -34.125 ...
  * lon                    (lon) float32 -59.875 -59.625 -59.375 -59.125 ...
  * time                   (time) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    Albedo_inst            (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    AvgSurfT_inst          (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    CanopInt_inst          (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    ECanop_tavg            (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    ESoil_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Evap_tavg              (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    LWdown_f_tavg          (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Lwnet_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    PotEvap_tavg           (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Psurf_f_inst           (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Qair_f_inst            (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Qg_tavg                (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Qh_tavg                (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Qle_tavg               (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Qs_acc                 (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Qsb_acc                (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Qsm_acc                (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Rainf_f_tavg           (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Rainf_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    RootMoist_inst         (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SWE_inst               (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SWdown_f_tavg          (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SnowDepth_inst         (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Snowf_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SoilMoi0_10cm_inst     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SoilMoi100_200cm_inst  (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SoilMoi40_100cm_inst   (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SoilTMP0_10cm_inst     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SoilTMP100_200cm_inst  (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SoilTMP10_40cm_inst    (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    SoilTMP40_100cm_inst   (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Swnet_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Tair_f_inst            (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Tveg_tavg              (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    Wind_f_inst            (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 40, 48), chunksize=(1, 40, 48)>
    time_bnds              (time, bnds) float64 dask.array<shape=(365, 2), chunksize=(1, 2)>
Attributes:
    CDI:                    Climate Data Interface version 1.6.9 (http://mpim...
    Conventions:            CF-1.4
    history:                Mon Feb  5 20:07:25 2018: /usr/bin/ncks -O -L 1 /...
    source:                 Noah_v3.3
    institution:            NASA GSFC
    missing_value:          -9999.0
    tavg definision::       past 3-hour average
    acc definision::        past 3-hour accumulation
    inst definision::       instantaneous
    title:                  GLDAS2.1 LIS land surface model output
    references:             Rodell_etal_BAMS_2004, Kumar_etal_EMS_2006, Peter...
    conventions:            CF-1.6
    comment:                website: http://ldas.gsfc.nasa.gov/gldas, http://...
    MAP_PROJECTION:         EQUIDISTANT CYLINDRICAL
    SOUTH_WEST_CORNER_LAT:  -59.875
    SOUTH_WEST_CORNER_LON:  -179.875
    DX:                     0.25
    DY:                     0.25
    CDO:                    Climate Data Operators version 1.6.9 (http://mpim...
    NCO:                    20180205
```

when I try:

```
In[19]:pp.set_index('time').groupby(freq='1M').mean('time')
```

gives this error:

```
TypeError: groupby() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freq'
```

ok, knowing that there is this argument I will go to the next attempt which is:

```
In[20]:import pandas as pd
In[21]:pp.groupby(['Albedo_inst',pd.Grouper(key='‌​time', freq='M')]).mean()
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: `group` must be an xarray.DataArray or the name of an xarray variable or dimension
```

Last attempt was without frequency:

```
In[22]:pp.groupby('Albedo_inst').mean('time')
```

And the error:

```
ValueError: Level values must be unique: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] on level 0
```

I try:

```
gldas.resample('1MS', dim='time', how='mean')
```

error is:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Float64Index'
```

I try:

```
gldas.groupby('time.month').mean('time')
```

error is:

```
AttributeError: 'IndexVariable' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Would anyone help me? Thanks guys!

Edit:

```
In [24]: pp['time']
Out[24]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 365)>
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
Attributes:
    standard_name: time
    bounds: time_bnds
    units: day as %Y%m%d.%f
    calendar: proleptic_gregorian
```

EDIT:

If i open a file:

```
In[108]:gldas
Out[108]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                (bnds: 2, lat: 40, lon: 48, time: 1)
Coordinates:
  * lat                    (lat) float32 -34.875 -34.625 -34.375 -34.125 ...
  * lon                    (lon) float32 -59.875 -59.625 -59.375 -59.125 ...
  * time                   (time) float64 0.0
  * bnds                   (bnds) int64 0 1
Data variables:
    Albedo_inst            (time, lat, lon) float64 15.66 16.0 16.23 15.98 ...
    AvgSurfT_inst          (time, lat, lon) float64 302.8 302.3 302.3 302.4 ...
    CanopInt_inst          (time, lat, lon) float64 0.001 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    ECanop_tavg            (time, lat, lon) float64 2.48 0.89 0.16 0.0 0.02 ...
    ESoil_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float64 46.39 46.58 49.18 55.22 ...
    Evap_tavg              (time, lat, lon) float64 0.0001668 0.0001683 ...
    LWdown_f_tavg          (time, lat, lon) float64 369.5 368.3 366.8 365.6 ...
    Lwnet_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float64 -88.05 -87.24 -87.68 ...
    PotEvap_tavg           (time, lat, lon) float64 622.3 610.4 601.1 599.6 ...
    Psurf_f_inst           (time, lat, lon) float64 1.004e+05 1.006e+05 ...
    Qair_f_inst            (time, lat, lon) float64 0.01117 0.01144 0.01172 ...
    Qg_tavg                (time, lat, lon) float64 54.2 53.65 55.13 58.52 ...
    Qh_tavg                (time, lat, lon) float64 110.4 101.9 104.5 114.7 ...
    Qle_tavg               (time, lat, lon) float64 417.2 420.8 416.1 405.6 ...
    Qs_acc                 (time, lat, lon) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    Qsb_acc                (time, lat, lon) float64 0.00253 0.00335 0.00528 ...
    Qsm_acc                (time, lat, lon) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    Rainf_f_tavg           (time, lat, lon) float64 1.4e-06 5e-07 1e-07 0.0 ...
    Rainf_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float64 1.4e-06 5e-07 1e-07 0.0 ...
    RootMoist_inst         (time, lat, lon) float64 255.3 259.6 263.9 266.1 ...
    SWE_inst               (time, lat, lon) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    SWdown_f_tavg          (time, lat, lon) float64 793.9 789.7 791.5 794.6 ...
    SnowDepth_inst         (time, lat, lon) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    Snowf_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    SoilMoi0_10cm_inst     (time, lat, lon) float64 24.86 25.17 25.47 25.51 ...
    SoilMoi100_200cm_inst  (time, lat, lon) float64 254.4 258.8 266.1 274.1 ...
    SoilMoi40_100cm_inst   (time, lat, lon) float64 153.7 156.7 159.8 161.6 ...
    SoilTMP0_10cm_inst     (time, lat, lon) float64 293.8 293.5 293.4 293.7 ...
    SoilTMP100_200cm_inst  (time, lat, lon) float64 291.3 291.0 290.9 290.9 ...
    SoilTMP10_40cm_inst    (time, lat, lon) float64 292.4 292.2 292.1 292.2 ...
    SoilTMP40_100cm_inst   (time, lat, lon) float64 292.2 292.0 291.8 291.9 ...
    Swnet_tavg             (time, lat, lon) float64 669.5 663.3 663.0 667.7 ...
    Tair_f_inst            (time, lat, lon) float64 300.2 300.0 299.8 299.5 ...
    Tveg_tavg              (time, lat, lon) float64 368.3 373.3 366.8 350.4 ...
    Wind_f_inst            (time, lat, lon) float64 3.704 3.704 3.704 3.704 ...
    time_bnds              (time, bnds) float64 0.0 0.0
Attributes:
    CDI: Climate Data Interface version 1.6.9 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)
    Conventions: CF-1.4
    history: Mon Feb  5 20:07:25 2018: /usr/bin/ncks -O -L 1 /tmpdata/regridder/services_88661/cdoGLDAS_NOAH025_3H.A20100101.1500.021.SUB.nc4 /tmpdata/regridder/services_88661/deflatecdoGLDAS_NOAH025_3H.A20100101.1500.021.SUB.nc4
Mon Feb 05 20:07:21 2018: cdo -s -L -f nc4 -sellonlatbox,-60.0,-48.0,-35.0,-25.0 -selname,Albedo_inst,AvgSurfT_inst,CanopInt_inst,ECanop_tavg,ESoil_tavg,Evap_tavg,LWdown_f_tavg,Lwnet_tavg,PotEvap_tavg,Psurf_f_inst,Qair_f_inst,Qg_tavg,Qh_tavg,Qle_tavg,Qs_acc,Qsb_acc,Qsm_acc,Rainf_...
    source: Noah_v3.3
    institution: NASA GSFC
    missing_value: -9999.0
    tavg definision:: past 3-hour average
    acc definision:: past 3-hour accumulation
    inst definision:: instantaneous
    title: GLDAS2.1 LIS land surface model output
    references: Rodell_etal_BAMS_2004, Kumar_etal_EMS_2006, Peters-Lidard_etal_ISSE_2007
    conventions: CF-1.6
    comment: website: http://ldas.gsfc.nasa.gov/gldas, http://lis.gsfc.nasa.gov/
    MAP_PROJECTION: EQUIDISTANT CYLINDRICAL
    SOUTH_WEST_CORNER_LAT: -59.875
    SOUTH_WEST_CORNER_LON: -179.875
    DX: 0.25
    DY: 0.25
    CDO: Climate Data Operators version 1.6.9 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)
    NCO: 20180205/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/variableexplorer/utils.py:414: FutureWarning: 'summary' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
  display = value.summary()
```

Conclusion:
I got it. If anyone needs help, send me a message.

Comment: Why are you using `pp.groupby('Albedo_inst').mean('time')`? If this is `pandas` you should use `pp.groupby('Albedo_inst')['time'].mean()`

Comment: I try and: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'`

Comment: Your `pp['time']` is obviously a column containing string data. Convert it into desired format (int, float...) before using `mean()`.

Comment: I update in my question. My pp['time'] is zero in all. I don't understand.

Comment: What is the output of `ncdump -v time file.nc4`? Do you get non-zero values with xr if you open a single file?

Comment: I am trying `ncdump -v time file.nc4`. Yes, open a single file he is zero. I edit a post with the answer.

Comment: `ncdump -v time file.nc4` not work.

Comment: I got it. If anyone needs help, send me a message.

Comment: @LucasFagundes - it would be nice if you could post your solution as an answer to this question.

Comment: @jhamman I did not know I could post an answer to my question. I'll post yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get `xr.open_mfdataset`, so I had to create a new `ds` and go for it.

```
files = glob('./GLDAS_2010/*.nc4')

data = Dataset(files[0], mode='r')
albedo = 0

for file in files:
    dados = Dataset(file, mode='r')
    lons = dados.variables['lon'][:]
    lats = dados.variables['lat'][:]
    Albed = dados.variables['Albedo_inst'][0, :, :]
    time=datetime.strptime(file[-29:-16], '%Y%m%d.%H%M')
    ds = xr.DataArray(Albed, coords={'lat': lats, 'lon': lons,'time': time}, dims=['lat', 'lon']).to_dataset(name='Albedo')
    if type(albedo) == int:
        albedo = ds
    else:
        albedo = xr.concat([albedo, ds], 'time')

albedo = albedo.sortby('time')

mean_month = albedo.Albedo.resample(freq='M', dim='time')
```

Comment: Note that in `xarray` version `2022.12.0` `resample` didn't accept a `freq` argument, but the syntax of @Ethan Gutmann below did work

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have a valid time variable (time is always 0 in your sample above...) you'll have to fix that.  But once that is done, I think the line you are looking for is:

`gldas['Albedo_inst'].resample(time="1MS").mean(dim="time")`